# using Eval to set variable equal to multiple line string

Tags: bash, awk, eval

I am trying to use eval to set a multiline variable

```
$ k="A
B
C"

$ echo "$k"
A
B
C

$ eval 'k="1
2
3"'

$ echo "$k"
1
2
3
```

But I want to use awk to produce my variable with an awk script

```
$ echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[ \t]+"}{print "awkV=\""$0"\""}' 
awkV="1
2
3"

$ eval `echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[ \t]+"}{print "awkV=\""$0"\""}'`
$ echo "$awkV"
1 2 3

$ eval '`echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[ \t]+"}{print "awkV=\""$0"\""}'`'
-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
-bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: awkV="-bash"}`: command not found...
```

I need to put some sort of quote around the eval statement, but I am using both single and double quotes internally and single quoting will probably mess up the "$k" I am using inside the script as well.  I tried putting the executed code in a heredoc without success, though maybe I am doing that wrong.

Help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Note this is just a minimal example of the problem and not my full application.

Comment: Looks like your searching the wrong way. What is the big picture behind?  What are you really trying to achieve? For what purpose?

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Try `eval "$(echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[ \t]+"}{print "awkV=\""$0"\""}')"`.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find problems in your code.  In this case it identifies both the missing quotes and the use of (archaic) backticks.

Comment: Or `awkV=$(echo "$k" | awk '1'); echo "$awkV"` ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Shellcheck identifies the problems in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reusing your awk script as-is and assuming you do have a good reason for wanting to do this:

```
$ eval "$(echo "$k" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="[ \t]+"}{print "awkV=\""$0"\""}')"
```

```
$ echo "$awkV"
A
B
C
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for this and other reasons to use command substitution with `$(...)` instead of the old, fragile, quirky backticks.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  I have the $() in my script but typed the ` by force of habit.  I am really surprised I didn't try the double quote.